# Need help understanding terms related to PPF (Public Provident Fund) in India

Tags: india, investment-strategies, retirement-plan

ICICI Bank in India provides a PPF Scheme which offers an attractive 8.7% PA.
I was trying to figure out the interest that I could earn by using [this](http://www.icicibank.com/Personal-Banking/investments/ppf/ppf-calculator.page?#toptitle) PPF calculator of theirs.

There are a couple of things that I don't understand (I'm a newbie so some of the terms and things being asked by the calculator are really confusing)

[image]

**QUESTIONS**

Why is MY age important ?
Does it affect the total interest I earn in any way ?

What does "Subscription Option" mean ? It has values like Quarterly, Yearly, Monthly etc. Can someone please explain this to me ?

Lastly, I know this sounds really stupid but this is guaranteed returns right ? 
There's no risk involved here unlike Mutual Funds, Equity Investments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is MY age important ? Does it affect the total interest I earn in any way ?

Nope age is not relevant.

> What does "Subscription Option" mean ? It has values like Quarterly, Yearly, Monthly etc. Can someone please explain this to me ?

Will you deposit money every month or year.

> Lastly, I know this sounds really stupid but this is guaranteed returns right ? There's no risk involved here unlike Mutual Funds, Equity Investments

The return is garunteed by Govt. The rates are linked to small saving and change every year.

Comment: so if my age isn't relevant, any idea why they're asking it ? If the amount invested in 15000, then the subscription period determines how often I pay the installments for that amount ?  Have I understood that properly ?

Comment: @DhiwakarRavikumar To capture demographics, plus highlight that beyond a certain age, you can't opt into PPF.